# How can i clean the XCUIElement which type is textField?

Tags: objective-c, xcode-ui-testing

```
XCUIElement *textField = app.textFields[@"xxxxx"];
[textField tap];
[textField typeText:@"12345678910"];
XCUIElement *key = app.keys[@"xx"]; (the "xx" is delete key)
    for (int a=0; a<11; a++) {
        [key tap];
    }
```

---

What i want to achieve is

```
textfield.text = @""
```

---

This method is too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this helper function:

```
-(void)clearField:(XCUIElement *)textField {
    [textField doubleTap];
    [app.menuItems[@"Select All"]tap];
}
```

and calling it via:

```
[self clearField: app.textFields[@"Last Name"]];
```

Comment: it's a good method to solve my problem.thank you,I got a new way to solve similar problems.thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can use this little helper function to clear the text from a UITextField during a UITest:

```
- (void)clearTextField:(XCUIElement *)textField {
    NSString *text = textField.value;
    NSString *deleteString = [@"" stringByPaddingToLength:text.length withString:XCUIKeyboardKeyDelete startingAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", deleteString);

    [textField tap];
    [textField typeText:deleteString];
}
```

This function takes the current string from the text field and simulates a delete key press for each character of the string. It is much faster that tapping on the delete key a couple of times.

In your test you can then simply call:

```
[self clearTextField:textField];
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution to my problem，thank you very much。I just started learning UITest，thank you.